# Fetch json from API, create HTML code within a div per object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch, javascript-objects

I am fetching JSON results from an API I created. There's a dataset called Title with objects  in that JSON that I'd like to forEach through.  Then I want to append the following HTML code WITHIN a div and then append:

```
 <section class="section">
  <img src="IMAGE_FROM_API.PNG" class="image" />
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="title">
      OBJECT TITLE TITLE
    </h2>
    <p class="paragraph">ITEM DESCRIPTION</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want to append that code as there's an array that is created that has just the ITEM TITLE. I will use some other functions to grab the image and the description.

Comment: Ok, but did you have a question or specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Loop through the array, and use a template literal to create the HTML for that element.